# how to see the contents in the RAM when a program is executed in Linux?

Tags: linux, rhel, ram

I want to see the contents of a program being stored in RAM when the program is executed . I have used `cat /proc/[pid]/meminfo` but it gave only address and permission mode details . 
I also tried `pmaps -X pid` , it gave too many details but the data . How to see the content loaded on RAM ?

Answer (score 6):

`/proc/[pid]/mem` lets you access the virtual memory of a process.

Offsets in that file correspond to virtual addresses. `/proc/[pid]/maps` tells you which address ranges are backed by actual memory (and where the memory itself is backed by files).

All this is documented in the [proc(5)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manpage.

A process can only access the memory of processes which are run under the same user as itself, and which are not setgid/uid. It used to be the case that you had to [ptrace()](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) a process in order to access its memory via `/proc/[pid]/mem`, but this is **NO LONGER TRUE** since quite a while (more precisely, since this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e268337dfe26dfc7efd422a804dbb27977a3cccc) from January 2012 (v3.2+), whose purpose was to fix a security bug, also editorialized in a lwn [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/476947/)).

#### Practical example

In a terminal window:

```
% echo $$ # show our pid
6744
% read -sp 'secret pasword: '; echo
secret pasword:
%
```

Then in another terminal window:

```
% grep heap /proc/6744/maps
01bb7000-01c3e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
% dd if=/proc/6744/mem bs=1 skip=$((0x01bb7000)) count=$((0x01c3e000-0x01bb7000)) status=none |
    strings | less
...
% dd if=/proc/6744/mem bs=1 skip=$((0x01bb7000)) count=$((0x01c3e000-0x01bb7000)) status=none |
    strings | grep qwerty
qwertyuiop # here is the "secret password"
```

People generally use a debugger like `gdb` to peek at the memory of a running process instead of rudimentary ways like this (a debugger knows the format of the structures used by a process, can follow pointers, lists, etc), but the principle is basically the same.

Recent linux kernels also have nicer interfaces instead of `/proc/[pid]/mem`, like [`process_vm_readv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html). Just as with `/proc/[pid]/mem` or `PTRACE_PEEK`, etc. you need root-like privileges (`CAP_SYS_PTRACE`) in order to read the memory of a process you don't own.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt , first time when I read the example was not loaded in my phone , just now I saw it my laptop , sry for my early comment and thanks a lot for the help!!